# Only Show Multiple Instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Allright so I have this query that is pretty much pulling up ALL the info I got in my DB

```
Select 
p.ProjectName,
s.siteid,
c.PaperID,
m.MemberFirstName,
m.MemberLastName,
m.MemberDOB,
m.MemberID
From Sites s, Papers c, Members m, Projects p
Where s.SiteID=c.SiteID
and c.MemberID=m.MemberID
and s.ProjectID=p.ProjectID
order by ProjectName, MemberFirstName, MemberLastName
```

However, I just want to pear down my query to only display MULTIPLE instances of when a Member enters into multiple sites

Currently my results look something like the below output - so in this particular case I'd like to keep John Doe's results because he is showing up in multiple sites (his MemberID verifies that he is the same John Doe and not a different John Doe) but I do NOT want to keep Jane Doe's results because she only appears once on one site.

```
ProjectName | SiteID | PaperId |  MemberFirstName | MemberLastName | MemberDOB  | MemberID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project 1   | 123456 | 123     | Jane             | Doe            | 1991-01-01 | 12345
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project 1   | 789012 | 321     | John             | Doe            | 1991-02-02 | 54321
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Project 1   | 345678 | 456     | John             | Doe            | 1991-02-02 | 54321
```

Comment: Should John Doe appears twice or only once in your example?

Comment: Yep - he should appear twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if having the SiteID is important you could do something like:

```
SELECT
ProjectName,
siteid,
PaperID,
MemberFirstName,
MemberLastName,
MemberDOB,
MemberID
FROM (
    Select 
    p.ProjectName,
    s.siteid,
    c.PaperID,
    m.MemberFirstName,
    m.MemberLastName,
    m.MemberDOB,
    m.MemberID,
    COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY m.MemberID ) AS CNT
    From Sites s, Papers c, Members m, Projects p
    Where s.SiteID=c.SiteID
    and c.MemberID=m.MemberID
    and s.ProjectID=p.ProjectID
    ) A
WHERE CNT > 1
order by ProjectName, MemberFirstName, MemberLastName
```

Comment: Would like to keep the SiteID, ChartID, and ProjectName - however, running this query looks like it still gives me the same results where the members who just show up once in one site appear.

Comment: I'm getting correct results when I mock this up in sqlfiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27092/2  Looking at this again, I would use m.MemberID in the PARTITION BY clause instead of M.MemberFirstName and m.MemberLastName.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING`. Note that you won't be able to select the same data, as there will be multiple `SiteID`s per person.

Something like this:

```
Select 
  m.MemberFirstName,
  m.MemberLastName,
  m.MemberDOB,
  m.MemberID
From Sites s, Papers c, Members m, Projects p
Where s.SiteID = c.SiteID
  and c.MemberID = m.MemberID
  and s.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
order by ProjectName, MemberFirstName, MemberLastName
GROUP BY 
  m.MemberFirstName,
  m.MemberLastName,
  m.MemberDOB,
  m.MemberID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```